# How can I check for aaa or aab or a in a Perl string?

Tags: perl

Can anybody tell me what pattern do I need to write in the bind expression if I want to check whether the string contains aaa or aab or a?

```
$str = "Hello how are aaa you?";
print $str =~ m/what should i write here?/;
```

Comment: Do you mean the exact strings 'aaa', 'aab' and 'a' or are you interested in the more general case of checking for the presence of at least one of of three arbitrary strings?

Comment: You may want to read the fine manual (perldoc perlre, perldoc perlrequick, perldoc perlretut, see also http://perldoc.perl.org/ ) before asking questions here.  You'll find you can program much more effectively if you know the basics yourself, and only come to Stack Overflow for more advanced questions.

Comment: I think is actually an exercise in _Learning Perl_. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$str =~ /a|aaa|aab/
```

You might want to check the [regular operator precedence](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/lperl/ch08_05.htm) to make sure you don’t get caught by things like `/^foo|bar$/` (matches `^foo` or `bar$`, contrast with `^(foo|bar)$`).

Comment: You only need the first alternation there. You've never visited the other ones.

Comment: I assumed that the strings given were just examples and the poster wants to match any string alternation in general. Otherwise I’d have hard time imagining the use case for `/a|aaa|aab/`.

Comment: That's why you can use more than code to explain your answer. Despite what anyone says, code does not speak for itself, especially for people who don't know how to do it already.

Answer (score 6):

```
$str =~ /a/
```

(Think about it...)

Answer (score 3):

`(aaa|aab|a)`...

Answer (score 0):

Given mscha's point (answer not comment) I wonder if you really want to match and keep. If you want to know what you found try something like a global match captured to an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "Hello how are aaa you?";
my @found = $str =~ m/(aaa|aab|a)/g;
foreach my $result (@found) {
  print "found $result\n";
}
```

Comment: Really? What's the downvote for? We seem to be debating the OP as all he needs is to search for the letter 'a' and so I suggest that perhaps the OP wants to know which of the strings was matched. What was so wrong with that?